# how to show direction from my location to saved latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

i tried few of examples but it doesn't showing the direction and keep getting error. i want it to be like when i'm clicked the direction button, it redirect to google maps and show the direction from my current location to given destination latitude and longitude.

it's a java coding from android studio

```
if (destData != null) {
        final String dataHold = (String) destData.get("coordinate");
        dest.setText(dataHold);
        destAddress = dest.toString();

        direction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (source!=null){
                    String packageName = "com.google.android.apps.maps";
                    String query = String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%s",destAddress);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(query));
                    intent.setPackage(packageName);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(DirectionActivity.this,"please get current location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

picture of the current output i'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method and provide co-ordinate values.

```
 public static void startNavigationOnGm(Context context,double lat, double lng){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+lat+","+lng));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```